Error: Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration
I followed the documentation and I can't get a token. I even managed to install OpenSSL to make the key command work by installing Chocolatey first.
User.php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: 'UNIQ_IDENTIFIER_EMAIL', fields: ['email'])]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{

#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column]
private ?int $id = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 180)]
private ?string $email = null;

/**
 * @var list<string> The user roles
 */
#[ORM\Column]
private array $roles = [];

/**
 * @var string The hashed password
 */
#[ORM\Column]
private ?string $password = null;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): static
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUserIdentifier(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 *
 * @return list<string>
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}

/**
 * @param list<string> $roles
 */
public function setRoles(array $roles): static
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
 */
public function getPassword(): string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): static
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function eraseCredentials(): void
{
    // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
    // $this->plainPassword = null;
}

}

security.yaml
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            username_path: email
            password_path: password

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~

    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
security:
    password_hashers:
        # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
        # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
        # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
        # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
            algorithm: auto
            cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
            time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
            memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

routes.yaml
controllers:
resource:
    path: ../src/Controller/
    namespace: App\Controller
type: attribute
prefix: /api

api_login_check:
path: /api/login_check

lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
# token_ttl: 3600
user_identity_field: email

.env
(...)

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###

JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=8006dc845f442dd4914223aefb507182ab35cff77ae5457aa01130f61f57ea12

###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###

In the database I have 
When I run php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-token test@test.com
I get Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration.
I generated and regenerated the keys with the right passphrase from .env

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/532 Here for example they regenerate their keys and it works...

Your issue is probably due to your public/private keys.
Did you apply the JWT_PASSPHRASE value from your env file for both private and public keys ?
I suggest to recreate public/private keys using the JWT_PASSPHRASE from the env loaded by the server (env, env.local or env.{curr_env}.local)
Use this command to identify the correct one
symfony console debug:dotenv

